# Can you use nodejs with install4j

Tags: node.js, install4j

Can you use install4j with nodejs? I have a server I need to have an installer for, can install4j work with this?

If not do any of you know something that can/

Other installers seem that would take a lot of time to solve my issue, since I also need information from the user (like paths.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install anything with install4j. However, the installer requires a JRE to run so you have to bundle one with it, even though you don't need it for your installed application. Also, a lot of install4j's functionality is geared towards supporting Java launchers, so that will not be useful for you.

Comment: Yeah, its a weird issue I have because a lot of these installers I'm finding usually are allowed only on windows. I'm just trying to avoid having to have the user modify a config file to input their values which an installer would help with.