# Using Insall4j for a simple server (with no java)

Tags: node.js, install4j

Is there any way I can ignore all the java components that Install4J uses? For example not requiring the user to have java installed? I have a very simple executable that I would like the user to install onto their machine and I would like the user to be able to enter some input for things like port.

The issue is that Install4J requires you to have java downloaded, and it also installs a ton of unnessary items that I don't need for this project.

Reason I'm using Install4J is my company has a license for it, and its very clean and easy to use unlike something like Inno where its windows only and I would need to learn how to script it.

The project is a javascript nodejs file thats already been packaged. I just need a neat installer so that all the client needs to do is enter some information such as port and have the program read the xml file for the needed input.

Thanks.

EDIT: Seems to not be possible. See: [Can you use nodejs with install4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54486963/can-you-use-nodejs-with-install4j)

Comment: As I said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54486963/can-you-use-nodejs-with-install4j this is not possible.

Comment: Yup, thank you. @IngoKegel